# PHP - Error AADSTS50105 al hacer login contra Azure

Tags: php, azuread

Tengo una aplicación en php que, si el usuario no esta logado, lo redirige Azure para hacer el login. El código de la pagina de login es el siguiente:

```
use Jumbojett\OpenIDConnectClient;

$oidc = new OpenIDConnectClient(<url_login>);
$oidc->setRedirectURL(getenv(<url_redirec>));
$oidc->setResponseTypes(array('id_token'));
$oidc->setAllowImplicitFlow(true);
$oidc->addAuthParam(array('response_mode' => 'form_post'));

try {
    if($oidc->authenticate()) {
        ... obtengo la información del usuario
    }   
} catch (Exception $e) {
   ... capturo el error
}
```

El problema es que algunas veces, Azure muestra una pantalla suya con un error AADSTS50105.

Sería posible añadir alguna configuración a esa librería para que, si Azure da ese error, en lugar de mostrarselo al usuario, lo redirija a una pantalla mia donde yo pueda dar detalles de los pasos a seguir para solucionar este error, además de información extra propia de mi aplicación?

Espero vuestra respuesta.

Un saludo.

Comment: Solo dice error AADSTS50105 o te muestra mas detalles?

Comment: Azure muestra una pantalla con ese error porque el usuario no esta asignado a la aplicacion de AAD correspondiente y necesito saber si al yo redirigir ahi, si da ese error que me devuelva el control